# Node js server crashes after PUT request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, put

After making a put request, the app crashes with error

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
(node:21666) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Server up and running
(node:21666) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify
node:internal/process/promises:227
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:572:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/kayode/Desktop/learn-mern/auth/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/kayode/Desktop/learn-mern/auth/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:264:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/kayode/Desktop/learn-mern/auth/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at /Users/kayode/Desktop/learn-mern/auth/routes/users.js:36:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is my code...

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/User')

router.put('/:email', async (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(req.params._id)
    let email = req.params.email;
    let user = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }

    try {
        await User.findOneAndUpdate(email, user);
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify('200'));
        console.log('Here first')
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err) //not commented
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

But, if I try to make a another request (with postman), without refreshing the server it says sends a error **could not send request**

But then again, on line 36, "at /Users/kayode/Desktop/learn-mern/auth/routes/users.js:36:24" where it says `res.status(400).send(err) //not commented`
if I comment the line out (ie not return an error), the PUT request would be successful and another request after that would also work without refreshing or restartiung the server.

I know I can just comment that line out and move on, but I need to know what's happening, thanks!

Comment: Remove this line `res.send(req.params._id)`. Call res.send() only when the request to the database has returned. Also can you share why you are doing this (res.send(req.params._id)) at that point?

Comment: @joyce obi, thanks! that was a dumb typo i made. i used the id to get one user, switched back to using email and forgot to edit it.

Comment: Oh okay, good that it's been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the response in the beginning of the request and try to send it again in the end of the request (in line5) .

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/User')

router.put('/:email', async (req, res, next) => {
    let email = req.params.email;
    let user = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }

    try {
        await User.findOneAndUpdate(email, user);
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify('200'));
        console.log('Here first')
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err) //not commented
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```